# How to measure broadband noise

Tags: noise, test-equipment

I need to measure the noise performance of an DAC + Amplifier combination. The system has a bandwidth of ~100MHz and the expected noise level is approx. 1-2 mV rms.
What is the preferred instrument to do this?

I know there is the R&S URE3, which is only 30MHz and discontinued.
Is a spectrum analyzer the best choice? If yes which parameters are critical for this application?

Money is not an issue :)

Comment: If "money is no object" and you're looking at buying something, I'd simply ask the sales department of R&S and Keysight what they can offer. If this is only an exercise then look at these manufacturers websites, there are plenty of SA to choose from. Yes a SA is the most obvious choice.

Comment: What specifically do you mean when you say "noise performance"? Do you mean you want to measure the noise it produces or it's ability to avoid noise problems on power supplies.

Comment: All you need is a DSO with external load and AC coupled to 50 Ohm terminator for matched impedance from coax or 150 ohm from twisted pair to get full bandwidth.

Comment: @Andy aka : I mean the noise present at the output.